# Fetchmail: html version of mail

Tags: printing, email

I am trying to read mail from a pop3 server and print it through cups. I want to keep the html formatting of the email as it was received and that is where I am having trouble

On seeing header of every formatted email on the web client, I can see it has two versions in one email. One is text/plain version, without formatting. Other is text/html version which contains the html code of the formatted email. I am using fetchmail to retrieve the email and then mailx to read is. My problem is that I can only see the text/plain version. The html version is not available.

I have a doubt that fetchmail is somehow truncating the html version. My question consists of two parts:

1) How can I make fetchmail bring whole email i.e. with text/html part so that the original email can be generated

2) How can I print that email in html format (without html code, only output) to on the paper. I am using Raspbian with fetchmail, mailx and cups for the above mentioned tasks

I have tried mutt to read the email as well but with same results. So the problem is somewhere in fetching or forwarding it to the local user mailbox

EDIT: Upon using `cat /var/mail/username | grep html`, I can see the emails DO contain html versions. So the error is not with fetchmail. There is some thing I am missing with `mailx` or `mutt`, that is not displaying html version